# server closed the connection unexpectedly PSQL copy

Tags: postgresql

I have this error in my PostgreSQL 9.6 in google cloud and really don't know why. When trying to export large tables via copy. The table size is more or less 30GB and 16GB.

```
COPY data transfer failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I did quickly search in google and see these flag is important but I'm not sure if is true.

- shared_buffers=>2492MB
- temp_file_limit=>10268767kB.

And this is a configuration on Master and Slave

- vCPU=>2
- Memoria=>7,5 GB
- SSD=>109 GB
- PG 9.6

Any idea?

Comment: The postgreSQL server's log file should contain more info.

Comment: Thanks , @frlan i'll see the log again with more details